# Laravel: Return a button if two columns in a table are true, if not, don' return anything

Tags: twig

I need to loop through a table in .twig and if two columns are equal, it should return a button to delete., for example:

loop through boxes and if the quantity of boxes is equal to the available_quantity then I can show a delete button.

```
{% for toy in boxes.toys %}
  {% if toy.quantity == toy.available_quantity %}
    <a href="" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Right now, this returns a button for each true case. I just need one button if all are true, if on or all are false I dont want a button

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is something like this, as soon as you find a row where the quantities are different, set the value to false, so it'll never display the button:

```
{% set delete = true %}

{% for toy in boxes.toys %}
  {% if toy.quantity != toy.available_quantity %}
    {% set delete = false %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if delete %}
    <a href="" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</a>
{% endif %}
```

Unfortunately Twig hasn't got a way to then break out of the loop, so it'll continue to loop over all the entries, but that won't be a problem.

Alternatively, you can use this method which will only loop over entries that match a certain condition, to do basically the same thing:

```
{% set delete = true %}

{% for toy in boxes.toys if toy.quantity != toy.available_quantity %}
  {% set delete = false %}
{% endfor %}

{% if delete %}
    <a href="" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</a>
{% endif %}
```

In this case, it'll only loop over the entries which have the values not matching, and in that case, set delete to false.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a fix, not sure how ideal or correct this is. Im simply running the check inside the anchor tag and adding a hide class if quantities don't match up

```
<a href="" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger
  {% for toy in boxes.toys %}
    {% if toy.quantity != toy.available_quantity %}
      hide
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
">Delete</a>
```